# Computing the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{n^4+k}\sin \frac{2k \pi}{n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm pretty sure this is a Riemann sum, but I can't solve it. I tried to write it as the integral of a function which equals the product of $\sin(2 \pi x)$ and something, but so far it didn't work.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{n^4+k}\sin \frac{2k \pi}{n}$$

Comment: $L~=~-\dfrac1{4\pi}$

Comment: @Lucian: I just determined that using [Richardson extrapolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation) and the [ISC](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html), but I was trying to figure out a way to give a hint without simply stating the value. :) I suspect that Alexander would like a proof, not just the value of the limit, but I guess knowing the answer can be helpful in figuring out if your proof is valid.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Oddly enough, the series containing $n^2$ instead of $\sqrt{n^4+k}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22516/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-lucian).